# Why can I use the results of a query only once?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm new to SQL and psycopg2. I'm playing around a bit and try to find our how to display the results of a query. I have a small script where I make a connection to the database and create a cursor to run the query.

```
from psycopg2 import connect

conn = connect(host="localhost", user="postgres", dbname="portfolio",
               password="empty")

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM portfolio")

for record in cur:
    print("ISIN: {}, Naam: {}".format(record[0], record[1]))

print(cur.fetchmany(3))

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

If I run this code, the first print is fine, but the second print-statement returns [].

If I run only one of the two print-statements, I get a result every time.
Can someone explain me why?

Comment: The cursor returns an iterator, which can only yield the results once. `print()` exhausts it.

Comment: @roganjosh: Looking at [documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html), it doesnt seem to be the case.It shows an example of `print` in a `for` loop.

Comment: Please show me exactly where. I suspect that the for loop is actually iterating over the cursor, which is fine, since you're asking it to yield the result once. You would still have an empty iterator at the end of the loop

Comment: It appears that a change was made in v2.4 where [`itersize`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.itersize) limit was set to 2000. I think that may mean that it will fetch 2000 records at once.

Comment: Look at the [`scrollable`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.scrollable) attribute. Only scrollable cursors can be rewound, and you have to explicitly call `scroll`.

Comment: Try adding `records = cur.fetchall()`  and to iterate over this result.

Comment: While I haven't worked with psycopg, the use of `for` loop looks kind of weird because it gets exhausted on the 1st go as commented by @roganjosh

Comment: No, it gets exhausted when it has looped over all the results returned by the iterable you are looping over.

Comment: A list is _iterable_, you can loop over it, end-to-end as many times as you like. An _iterator_ is more like a waterfall; you can observe the water as it falls past you (This is `print()`), but nothing (forget rain) is going to put that water you just watched back at the top.

Comment: @tripleee: And I thought iterable means something you iterate over just as you would do in `for line in file`? In that case, there is no need to use `for` and expect it to return 1 record at a time?

Comment: Really, you seem to have drawn hasty conclusions from what everyone is saying here and just going deeper into confusion. We're not going to be able to help here unless you do some research on _iterators_

Comment: I am not confused. I am thinking - why is `cursor` returning all records at one go into a `record` than returning 1 entry per row. This is the difference I see as compared to regular iterating over the list example. You may choose not to help.

Comment: `records = cur.fetchall()` is a converience which is equivalent to `records = [rec for rec in cur]` - it's the `fetchall()`, not the `for` loop, which returns everything at once. If you want help, ask a new question instead of attempting to drive this in a new direction with endless comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cursor loops over the results and returns one at a time. When it has returned all of them, it can't return any more. This is precisely like when you loop over the lines in a file (there are no more lines once you reach the end of the file) or even looping over a list (there are no more entries in the list after the last one).

If you want to manipulate the results in Python, you should probably read them into a list, which you can then traverse as many times as you like, or search, sort, etc, or access completely randomly.

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM portfolio")

result = cur.fetchall()

for record in result:
    print("ISIN: {}, Naam: {}".format(record[0], record[1]))

print(result[0:3]))
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you can add as to why a `for` loop returns everything at once, which isnt generally the case.

Comment: @shahkalpesh it doesn't. It's worth re-reading the comments and answer, nobody is suggesting it does.

Comment: @roganjosh: I dont know what you mean by that. What I am suggesting (based on my limited knowledge of python and psycopg), why would a `for ... in cursor` not iterate for every record?

Comment: It absolutely does; why are you insisting it doesn't?

Comment: When I say iterate, I mean it goes through each record and executes a `print` statement for every record as one would do when using `for` over a list. Also, your code does a `fetchall` which isnt what OP has done. I am looking for an explanation on why an iterable exhausts at one go (when I dont use `fetchall`). Thank you.